# Problem with filter method using dataset attribute

Tags: javascript

my project does the following:
1/create a Book constructor function
2/ make instances and push them to an array
3/ map through the array and display items dynamically
4/ remove a certain array item upon clicking a button , yet when i  filter the array using data attribute nothing changes and the array stays the same and i can't find a solution please help!
[image: sample of my code]

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should remove whitespaces around `${book.title}` in the 21st line.

Comment: A _guess_ it not an answer. Then you shouldn't answer (and therfore reward) such low-quality and off-topic questions. And stuff like this, removing some whitespace, should be closed as "just a typo/not reproducible" because this only helps OP and not a future reader because that's too specific of a problem.